# Solve the explicit formula of a row vector

Tags: number-theory

Given that I have a matrix with the following style:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_0\\
\alpha_1\\
\vdots\\
\alpha_n
\end{pmatrix}_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}
$

where, $\alpha_i=(\alpha_{0,0},\alpha_{0,1},\cdots,\alpha_{0,n})$

In addition, we obtain $\alpha_i$ by rotating the $\alpha_0$ to right with $i$ steps. For instance,

If $\alpha_0=(1,2,4,8,16)$, then $\alpha_1=(16, 1, 2, 4, 8)$, $\alpha_2=(8,16, 1, 2, 4)$ and so on.

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 2 && 4 && 8 && 16\\
16 && 1 && 2 && 4 && 8 \\
8 && 16 && 1 && 2 && 4  \\
4 && 8 && 16 && 1 && 2 \\
2 && 4 && 8 && 16 &&  1 
\end{pmatrix}_{5 \times 5}
$

Given $\alpha_0=(\alpha_{0,i}=2^i)$ which has an **explicit formula**, so I would like to know is it possible to denote $\alpha_i$ using an explicit formula.

- How to solve this explicit formula of $\alpha_i$?

Answer (score 2):

Define $$J:=\left[\matrix{0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\0 & 0 &\cdots & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &0}\right]=\left[\matrix{e_{n+1} & e_1 & \cdots & e_{n-1} & e_n}\right]$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$-th column of the identity matrix of dimension $n+1$. Then your matrix can be written as
$$\left[\matrix{\alpha_0\\ \alpha_0J\\ \vdots\\ \alpha_0J^n}\right]$$
and $$\alpha_i=\alpha_0J^i$$